# NOT LIKE FILTER on table in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have three tables on a report where I would like to filter the [NAMN] field so it only contains rows where the [NAMN] field contains "IKKE PROVISJON". Which values can I put in the Tablix Properties?

I can't choose = since the field could be "Smith - IKKE PROVISJON"

[Tablix Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrovV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the expression to the field you want to filter by (NAMN in your case).

Set the Operator to `Like`

Set the Value to `*IKKE PROVISJON*` including the `*`

Check the following links for more information on filtering in reports and how to configure the expressions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-filter-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/filter-equation-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you so much!

BonusQuestion:
What can I do if I want a filter for only NAMN that does not contain IKKE PROVISJON?

Comment: I'm not sure until I can l get back to my PC and check, but you need to start a new question anyway, and if this answered your initial question, please mark it as accepted (the check mark to the left below the vote up/down buttons)